# On router link click event - angular2

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Hey I have this component **(this is my parent controller)**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'user.component.html'
})


export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    isCompleted: Boolean = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.router.events.subscribe((v) => {
            this.isCompleted = true;
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

`UserComponent.isCompleted` is a variable used by loading bar. 
I have subscribed to router events and value of `UserComponent.isCompleted` will be changed when router done loading. I need to change `UserComponent.isCompleted` to `false` on router link click.
I know I can do it with `click event` like this:

```
<a class="item" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" (click)="myFnc()">Dashboard</a>
```

But I looking for any other way to make it global.

Comment: Maybe create your own directive which will listen onClick event?